# Помещение одного изображения под другое в android

Tags: android

Не знаю на сколько я адекватно выразился в заголовке, но проблема такая: **mImageSight** должен быть всегда поверх других изображений, но получается так, что изображение в анимации **mAnimImg** накладывается поверх **mImageSight**. При добавлении картинки из галереи, она накрывает все остальные изображения. Как можно отрегулировать все так, чтобы **mImageSight** был всегда в самом верхнем слое, посередине **mAnimImg** и нижним слоем была картинка из галереи. И заодно еще один вопрос задам, как сделать неограниченное добавление изображений с удалением старого? Получается так, что у меня вылетает приложение при попытке загрузить новое изображение. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

код:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private ImageView mImageSight;
    private ViewGroup mMoveSight;
    private ImageView mAnimImg;
    private TranslateAnimation transfer;
    private float mX;
    private float mY;
    private float xX;
    private float yY;
    static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        xX = metrics.widthPixels;
        yY = metrics.heightPixels;
        mMoveSight = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.move_sight);
        mImageSight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sight);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
        mImageSight.setLayoutParams(lParams);
        mImageSight.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mAnimImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thing);
        Button animator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anima);
        animator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("checkk", "Animation started");
                mAnimImg.startAnimation(transfer);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();


        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                mX = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                mY = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (X - mX);
                layoutParams.topMargin = (int) (Y - mY);
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                transfer = new TranslateAnimation(0, (X - mX - xX + 285), 0, (Y - mY - yY + 345));
                transfer.setDuration(2000);
                transfer.setFillAfter(true);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.d("checkk", "Image set");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/move_sight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sight_ready_w"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thing"
        android:
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/thing_ready"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/anima"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="132sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:text="GetImg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: покажите разметку

Comment: используйте view.setZ()

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Помогло!